# How to get text from the form and save in text file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, activexobject

How to get text from the form and save in text file using javascript

```
   <html >
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"  href="/favicon1.png" sizes="16x16" />
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Login & Registration System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
   <body>
 <center>
 <div id="login-form">
 <form method="post">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
 <td><font color="#001c4e" size=18px >
   <b>Elvis Login</b></font></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" id="resultname" name="user_name"   placeholder="User ID" required /></td>
 </tr>
   <tr>
 <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Your Password" required /></td>
 </tr>
<div id="result"></div>
 <script>
  // Check browser support
   function WriteToFile(f) { //added the form you clicked from
try {
alert("started");
    var t = f.user_name.value;
    alert(t);
     var msg =  t;
     var fso, s;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    s = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Test\\Logfile.txt", 8, false);
    s.writeline(msg);
    s.Close();
    alert("Comment Saved!");
}
catch (err) {
    var strErr = 'Error:';
    strErr += '\nNumber:' + err.number;
    strErr += '\nDescription:' + err.description;
    document.write(strErr);
  }
}
  $</script>
  <tr>
  <td><button type="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this.form)" name="btn-login">Sign In</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
    </center>
    </body>
   </html>
```

I need get the username from form and save it in the text file.But this code only works in the IE browser.please give suggestions.
         what are the things used insteadof new ActiveXObject??
      I am not interested to install the plugins.give others suggestions please

Comment: Why do you want to save the username into a file? Exist cookies for that! It's more secure. IE does have methods to enable "trusted" applications to use ActiveX objects to read/write file but you can't do this in any cross-browser way

Comment: @AralRoca i need to save the username and  retrive the username from text file it will be used in another server.

Comment: @AralRoca please help me to save the username in text file.give suggestion insteadof ActiveX objects